# Why is my <a> tag is inheriting 'display:block' in one set of code, but not the other?

Tags: css

I was fiddling around with creating some headers with a navigation.  More specifically I was trying to create the nav links so that they would have padding so that the surrounding area would be clickable, and not just the text itself.

Usually in order to get this sort of behavior you need to apply padding to the `a` tag and use the `display: block` property:

```
li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

In my codepen that I have [here](http://codepen.io/MrAdam/pen/JKRVGv) I am able to achieve the clickable surrounding without applying `display: block`.  However in [this here](http://codepen.io/MrAdam/pen/pbEmJL) similar piece of code that I found off the internet, you must have `display: block` in order to get the padding area to be clickable, or even show.

Why do I not need to insert the `display: block` property in the first codepen link?  Is it inheriting that property from li?  If so, why is the second set of code not inheriting it?

Comment: You are required to show the code you are comparing here. Using a third-party site means that code can change or disappear tomorrow and help no one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily *HAVE* to add `display:block` to the `a` in order to achieve the desired effect. An inline element can handle padding just as a block can.

Example:

```css
div{
  background:red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom:20px;  /* just for visual purpose */
}

span{
  background:lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>Block</div>
<span>Inline</span>
```

The difference between the two Codepen examples you provided is that in the second one, the `ul` is hiding the link's padding by enforcing an `overflow: hidden` style.

Removing that `overflow` style from the `ul` will allow the `a` tags (links) to visibly show the padding that they have.

Comment: Please explain the downvote, thanks!

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The real magic of the method is that without having given the element a set height, when you set overflow to hidden it takes on the height of the inner elements.

please remove this on ul style

```
overflow:hidden;
```

add background color to this

```
li a
{
background-color:#333;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good answer for the questions of the OP. You should add some explanation about why he should change his code/answer to his questions (I think).